# Django Get Range in Queryset

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

In my Django app, I have a somewhat large collection of models ordered by the amount of times they've completed an action. It's a leaderboard. **I want people using my app to see what place they're in, and the names of two people above and two people below them.** So I'd need to find the position of the user in question in that queryset, and then find the two users above and below him. What is the most efficient way to accomplish that? I'm drawing blanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the objects by the score, using `score__lt` and `score__gt`.

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    score = models.IntegerField()

    def get_score_above_below(self, n):
        try:
            above = Participant.filter(score__lt=self.score).order_by('-score')[:n]
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            above = Participant.filter(score__lt=self.score).order_by('-score')
        try:
            below = Participant.filter(score__gt=self.score).order_by('-score')[:n]
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            below = Participant.filter(score__gt=self.score).order_by('-score')

        entries = list(above) + [self] + list(below)
        return [(part.user, part.score) for part in entries]
```

This would return a list of tuples:

```
[('<username two places above>', score),
 ('<username one place above>', score),
 ('<instance username>', score),
 ('<username one place below>', score),
 ('<username two places below>', score)]
```